# GAE - {% trans %} doesn't work in django templates while ugettext() does

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization

I've setup my python AppEngine work with i18n internatiolization support. Getting texts from locales in code works fine, while {% trans "x" %} in django templates don't.

Here is what I have in a sample template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Home" %}
Language: {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

It just always outputs "Home" and Language is empty. When I write _("Home") in code, everything is fine, I get it translated.

My folder structure:

```
/
/lib - third parties
/locale
/locale/en
/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
/locale/ru_RU
/locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES
/static - static files
/source - python files
/source/templates - django templates
```

In my app.yaml

```
libraries:
    - name: django
    version: "1.2"
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the link to my test project, which illustrates the issue... Just a couple of files there.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C010011792A4B538!131

Answer (score 0):

About `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}`, You have to configure in `settings.py` the context processor `i18n` like that:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    ...
```

But I don't think there is a rapport with your problem with the templatetag `{% trans %}`.

Comment: Tried that, nothing changed... If you have a couple of minutes, have a look at the sample project that I uploaded a minute ago.